# Difference between Tor Browser and Tor Expert Bundle

Tags: configuration

I was using the Tor Browser to crawl a few google results with a program in C# and selenium. I decided to take the next step and use the Tor Expert Bundle. I set the socks port, control port, control password hash, geoip/geoip6/data location properly in the torrc file, and when I run it shows that is running ok.

The problem is: seems to me that Google blocks me much more when I am using the Tor Expert Bundle than when I am using the Tor Browser, this makes any sense? Is possible that the Tor Browser has a configuration that I am not using? What am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Same Tor underneath, TBB just has the browser bundled on top of the Tor connection whereas expert is just the connection with no browser. They both path through the network exactly the same way (so that you can't tell them apart, which is the whole point of Tor, to make us all look the same).

I would imagine any difference between the two is either coincidence or only perceived.

Comment: Hard to believe that is a coincidence. I did several trials, but I will try again. Maybe it can be that with the Browser I am running under ports 9150 and 9151 (socks and control respectively) and with the expert bundle I am using 6150 and 6151? This makes any sense?